# Berachah LeVatalah (blessing in vain) retroactively

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, bracha-levatala

Can a Berachah be made LeVatalah retroactively?

What if you eat something that is spoiled, not realizing it until a bite or two in?  You would not make a Berachah on spoiled food.  But if you did, and you ate it, and then you realized it was spoiled, does your Berachah retroactively become in vain?  Would it make a difference if you had either an extreme reaction or a neutral reaction?

Comment: similar to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17077/if-a-person-voids-a-purchase-sale-what-happens-to-the-bracha

Comment: A similar case would be if you say Hamapil and can't fall asleep

Comment: _May nafka minah_ if it's _l'vatala_?

Comment: @GershonGold, yes, they are related. I think this is more fundamental to that, though. That's a particular application with other considerations (status of the sale being a big one).

Comment: @msh210 If you have to do teshuvah

Comment: @msh210, I was going to say what ba said.

Comment: @ba SethJ Teshuva for a shogeg/oneis on a derabanan? Also, that is classically the second worst possible nafka mina (the first being kiddushin al tenai X).

Comment: @DoubleAA, excuse me? We say Berachoth LeHakel because the _institution_ of Berachoth is MiDeRabbanan, whereas Motzi Shem HaShem LeVatalah is an Isur DeOraitha. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @SethJ Bracha levatala is not shem hashem levatala for most rishonim. In a bracha levatala you say a praise of hashem "He created fruits! That makes Him awesome!" so it isn't shem hashem levatala.

Comment: related question (note the last line in my comment) http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9707/oseh-maaseh-braishis-on-a-rainbow-is-this-a-brocho-levatoloh#comment22888_12215

Comment: @DoubleAA, how is your earlier comment consistent with this?  In the rainbow case you're saying "G-d created the world! He is awesome!"

Comment: @SethJ What's the problem? It's bracha levatala but not shem hashem levatala.

Comment: @DoubleAA There's no teshuvah for a shogeg on a derabanan?

Comment: @ba Not that God wouldn't accept it, just it might not be necessary.

Comment: @DoubleAA Why not? Do you have a source?

Comment: @ba Nesivos 234:3. I'm guessing not all agree, but it is a known and serious opinion.

Comment: @DoubleAA [VeAmar Rav VeIthema R"L VeAmri Lah R' Yoḥanan VeR"L DeAmri Travayhu, "Kol HaMeVarech Berachah SheEinah Tzerichah 'Over MiShum 'Lo Thisa.'"](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=brachos&daf=33a) - "Anyone who recites an unnecessary blessing violates the Biblical prohibition against taking G-d's name in vain." (My simplified translation of Ber. 33a, 3rd line from the bottom.)

Comment: @SethJ IIRC pretty much everyone but the Rambam takes that as an asmachta.

Comment: @SethJ See Aruch HaShulchan OC 215:5 http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%98%D7%95#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A8.D7.98.D7.95_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.94

Comment: Onus rachmana patra.

Comment: @AniYodeya Nonetheless, see the end of [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16408).

Comment: If you're at all uncertain if a food is spoiled, you should probably taste it - [without recite a *berakhah*](http://halachayomit.co.il/en/ReadHalacha.aspx?halachaid=777) - in order to find out and, if it's still good, proceed as usual (i.e. recite a *berakhah* and eat).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See SA OC 206, 6:
If he took in his hand a fruit in attempt to eat it, and the fruit fell from his hand and gets lost, or dirty and is lo unfit for consumption, ... He needs to say Baruch Shem Kevod Malchouto Leolam Vaed because he pronounced the name of G-d in vain.

So, **at the time of the blessing there was no error and the blessing was appropriate in the circumstances. But retroactively it was unnecessary.** The SA called this pronouncing the name of G-d in vain.

This Shulchan Aruch is from the Talmud Yerushalmi Berachot (folio 43b, chapter 6, halacha 1).

Comment: But there is a difference: in your case he never bit into it, and certainly never swallowed anything (=having *hana'ah*). In the OP's question he **did** eat a bite or two, thereby giving his body some benefit (albeit not for his taste buds...).

Comment: @Ploni if he eats chas veshalom feces and eat a bit or two.... see the sugia of shemen zayt and kemach seorim

Comment: I would think there's a difference between feces and spoiled bread... Where is this sugia you mentioned?

Comment: @Ploni shemen zayit is in the first or second amud of ketsad mevarchim and the sugia of mazik is there in rishonim and they report the kemach seorim perhaps my remember is not exact

Comment: Is spoiled food damaging to the body as is the case by olive oil?

Comment: @Ploni very posdibly

Comment: http://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/features/do-food-expiration-dates-matter

Answer (score 0):

On your first question regarding the possibility of a bracha levatala retroactively being made, this article by [dinonline](http://dinonline.org/2011/03/01/berachos-beracha-levatala/) explains

> 11. What if one recited a b’racha for a drink and it suddenly spilled?
>
> If possible, he should drink even a minute amount of the remnants in
>   order to use the b’racha. Otherwise, he has unfortunately recited a
>   b’racha levatala and must say the sentence baruch sheim etc.

For the 2nd part of your question regarding spoiled food, the [OU](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos/thurs_10_11_12/) writes,

> ...'If one eats moldy bread or other spoiled foods; one would recite
>   shehakol. (If one eats his fill of such bread, he would need to
>   bentch, which is a Biblical obligation – see Bi’ur Halacha 204:1 s.v.
>   pas she’ifasha.) This is only if the food is a little distasteful; if
>   it is truly unfit to eat, one would say no bracha on it at all.'

Seemingly, if the food was so spoiled a bracha shouldn't have been made in the first place, it may be a bracha levatala as well.

Comment: For the question asked: yes, there is a retroactive bracha levatala. For the example given: no, that's not levatala, since you've already eaten some of the food (and received at least a minuscule amount of hana'ah)