# If a Tallit is thoughtlessly brought into a bathroom, is it still ok?

Tags: mistakes, tallit-gadol, bathroom

If a Tallit was thoughtlessly taken into a bathroom - for example to remove a stain - is it defiled, or can it still be used?

Comment: Thank you so kindly. This really means a lot to know this. Thank you again for taking the time to answer this!  Best and blessings to you.

Comment: Welcome, elle, to Mi Yodeya. I'm glad you got an answer to your question; thanks for having brought it here! I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 6):

Don't worry about it. The practice of not bringing a Tallit into a bathroom is a strong custom (because the Tallit is a garment designated for prayer times, as opposed to the undergarment *tallit katan* which we do bring into the bathroom), but not technically a law. This is why you can make the blessing on it, then have in mind to remove it, use the restroom, and put it back on without another blessing -- you could *theoretically*, at the letter-of-the-law level, kept it on the whole time.

Rabbi Yaakov of Lisa -- known as the *Nesivos* -- writes ([Nesivos HaMishpat 234:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41534&st=&pgnum=104)) that if one violated a Rabbinic commandment by mistake (and we mean a real mistake), then further repentance is not required -- just make sure not to do it again. That would certainly be the same here, when all we're dealing with is a custom.

A Tallit is simply a four-cornered garment with the right knots and strings on it. You can't invalidate it by bringing it into the bathroom. It still accomplishes the same goal, i.e. fulfilling the Torah's commandment to have fringes on our four-cornered garments.

But please don't bring a Tallit into the bathroom.

Comment: Do you have a link to the Nesivot?

Comment: @Menachem it's famous in yeshivish circles, don't have the source off-hand.

Comment: @Menachem It's in CM regarding selling nevelah to someone by accident. I've definitely linked to it on Mi Yodeya a couple times

Comment: @DoubleAA: Found it here http://www.eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=48&cat=7&newsletter=118&article=384: "_The questioner cited the Netivot Hamishpat’s opinion (234:2) that if one unknowingly (b’shogeg)violates a rabbinic law, he does not require atonement, because, under those circumstances, it is not considered that he committed a sin._"

Comment: Do you have a source that this is an established custom according respect to the Tallith, as opposed to best practices to avoid soiling it?

Comment: @Menachem http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18778/berachah-levatalah-blessing-in-vain-retroactively#comment45963_18778