# What should you do if you washed and planned to have a meal with bread but realized that the bread went bad?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, bread

Say you had in mind to have a regular meal with bread. After washing and saying homotzi lechem min harataz and taking a bite of bread, you realize that the bread is bad.

Now all you have left to eat is mezonot/shechokol/etc.

Do you say an individual bracha for each food category and their respective bracha acharonas or does the single bite of bread cover everything. If the latter, what is the bracha acharona?

Is there a difference if you ate a bite of the spoiled bread (less than a kezayit) or if you ate no bread at at all? Do you have an obligation to take a bite?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18778

Comment: If you don't take a bite, it's definitely a blessing in vain. Besides, how would you know it's bad if you didn't take a bite? I'm therefore going to assume that when you wrote "Do you have an obligation to take a bite?" you meant "Do you have an obligation to swallow [even] the first bite?", and edited accordingly.

Comment: @Ploni I wouldn't make the assumption that the OP meant swallow. What if you noticed the bread was moldy when you picked it up: do you have to take a bite from it?

Comment: @Scimonster In the first paragraph he writes "After ... taking a bite of bread, you realize that the bread is bad", so you already took the bite, but don't want to swallow it.

Comment: @Ploni And the last paragraphs asks "Is there a difference if you ate a bite ... or if you ate no bread at at all?"

Comment: @Scimonster Meaning you bit into it and wanted to spit it out.

Comment: @Ploni Not necessarily. I would leave the OP's wording unless they decide to change it.

Comment: I think this question is far more interesting if you realize the bread is bad _before_ taking a bite.

Answer (score 3):

Rabbi Moshe Feinstein writes [(Igrot Moshe O.C. cheilek 4, 41)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14677&st=&pgnum=72) that less than a kezayit of bread does not exempt subsequent foods from their brachot, so in your case (assuming your bite was less than a kezayit) you would make bracha rishona and achrona on the rest of your meal, just as if you hadn't had any bread at all.

Comment: For those who want to look it up themselves, the most relevant part is on page  עא, left column, paragraph  beginning with וגם.

Comment: He seems to say there's a safek whether or not they're exempted.

Comment: @Ploni You mean when he says you shouldn't put yourself into a situation of safek? He's saying you need to know if you're planning on having a kezayit, because otherwise you have a safek if the other foods need a bracha - if ultimately you will finish the kezayit, then the bracha of hamotzi exempts the other foods now, even before you do so. But if you won't, then they need their own bracha. But he's not saying there's a safek if it exempts in a case where the kezayit will not be completed.